# Implementing memory management system using Linked

Tags: python, memory-management, linked-list

Currently I'm developing a operating system memory management simulate program using linked List data structure consents and my all the scenarios and oop concepts are fine.  When I run my code allocation part interpreter says there is a nonteype attribute error. It confuses me.  It works for all parts in my code except my `ishole` attribute.  Can any one tell me the error?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,size,hole_or_not,s_index,e_index,psid):
        self.block_size=size
        self.ishole=hole_or_not
        self.stat_index=s_index
        self.end_index=e_index
        self.ps_id=psid
        self.next=None 

class MemoryManagement:
    def __init__(self,os_size=400,totalsize=2560):
        self.head=Node(os_size,False,0,os_size-1,'os')
        self.head.next=Node(totalsize-os_size,True,os_size,totalsize,'free')
        self.totalfreespace=totalsize-os_size
        self.os_allocated=os_size

    def allocate(self,pid,size):
        current=self.head
        while current.ishole!=False or current.block_size<size:
            if current.ishole and current.block_size==size:
                current.ps_id=pid
                current.ishole=False
            elif current.ishole and current.block_size>size:
                hold_start_memory_address=current.stat_index
                hold_end_memory_address=current.end_index
                hold_block_size_current=current.block_size
                current.ps_id=pid
                current.block_size=size
                current.end_index=hold_start_memory_address+size-1
                current.ishole=False
                remain=Node(hold_block_size_current-size,True,hold_start_memory_address+size,hold_end_memory_address-1,'free')
                remain.next=current.next
                current.next=remain
            current=current.next
        else:
            print('----')

    def printstack(self):
        current=self.head
        while current.next:
            print(current.ps_id,current.block_size,current.stat_index,current.end_index,current.ishole)
            current=current.next
```

Then I used my follow test cases

```
o=MemoryManagement()
o.allocate('p1',100)
o.allocate('p2',500)
o.allocate('p3',1200)
o.allocate('p4',1000)
o.printstack()
```

Then I got error like this, but I can't understand why.  It happens on attribute `ishole` only

```
  while current.ishole!=False or current.block_size<size:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ishole'
  [Finished in 0.13s]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed algorithm in the function `allocate()` of the `class MemoryManagement` presents some missing in the logic.

**Problem 1** - split the `while-else` loop in one `while` loop and one `if-else` condition.

> The main `while` loop allow to explore all existing Nodes. If all
>   Nodes have been checked without allowing to allocate the `pid` ==>
>   'not enough memory'.

```
def allocate(self,pid,size):
    current=self.head
    while (current is not None):
        ...
        current=current.next
        # not enough memory to allocate
```

> Then for each `current` Node, check if the enough `size` is available.
>   When one Node allow to add the allocated `pid`, simply return.

The `current=current.next` has to be moved in the `while` loop (above).

```
        if current.ishole!=False or current.block_size<size:
            print("current: %s" % (str(current)))
            if (current.ishole):
                if (current.block_size > max_size):
                    max_size = current.block_size
            if current.ishole and current.block_size==size:
                current.ps_id=pid
                current.ishole=False
            elif current.ishole and current.block_size>size:
                hold_start_memory_address=current.stat_index
                hold_end_memory_address=current.end_index
                hold_block_size_current=current.block_size
                current.ps_id=pid
                current.block_size=size
                current.end_index=hold_start_memory_address+size-1
                current.ishole=False
                remain=Node(hold_block_size_current-size,True,hold_start_memory_address+size,hold_end_memory_address-1,'free')
                remain.next=current.next
                current.next=remain
                # successfully allocated then return
                return
            #current=current.next <== replaced by the while-loop above
        else:
            print('----')
```

**Bonus 1** - add a boolean returned value from the `allocate()` function.

> In the above proposed source code, it could be useful to return
>   `False` when the allocation fails (just after `# not enough memory to
>   allocate`) or to return `True` when allocation succeeds (just after `#
>   successfully allocated then return`).

Comment: Thanks for your help